# PGSQL function to split table on a delimiter on a particular column

Tags: function, postgresql, split, union, delimiter

I'm currently migrating a few databases from excel format to PostgreSQL. A few of them has records in one row, separated by a delimiter. I'm trying to write a function that transforms a table by separating chosen column by a chosen separator in the following way:

```
create table janek.temp (a integer, b text);
insert into janek.temp values (1, 'cat');
insert into janek.temp values (2, 'dog;hound');
```

this table contains 2 rows, I'd like to have a function that when I execute:

```
select * from janek.split_table ('janek', 'temp', 'b', ';')
```

I get 3 rows returned:

```
1;'cat'
2;'dog'
2;'hound'
```

Currently problems that I strugge with is 
- don't know how to pass schema name and table name to `RETURNS setof $1.$2 AS`
- first executed query doesn't work for reasons I don't understand , error pasted below

I hope that my logic is clear to you guys. I've provided sample data and the desired result. I'm new to PGSQL functions and don't know much, but I hope the code I've written is something easy to work on.

I hope that this function will be reused, it seems very helpful for data migration to me.

here's the code for my function:

```
create or replace function janek.split_table (table_schema text, table_name text, column_name text, separator text)
  RETURNS setof $1.$2 AS
    -- don't know how to pass table_schema.table_name as variable - need help here, this line doesn't work, but after manually entering schema and table name it works
$BODY$
DECLARE

    -- string variable containing sql queries to execute
    execute_query text;

    -- string variable where column list of target table will be assigned, except for one column - column_name
    column_list text;

    -- variable where maximal count of separator will be assigned
    separator_count integer;

BEGIN

    -- assigning variable column_list

    -- first error here, that I don't understand - when I execute this select statement manually it returns one column containing one string:
    -- ERROR:  query "SELECT 'array_to_string(array(select column_name::text 
    --  from information_schema.columns 
    --  where table_name = '''||table_name||'''
    --  and table_schema = '''||table_schema||'''
    --  and column_name <> '''||column_name||'''
    --  ), ', ');'" returned 2 columns
    -- CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "split_table" line 15 at assignment
    execute_query := 'SELECT array_to_string(array(select column_name::text 
    from information_schema.columns 
    where table_name = '''||table_name||'''
    and table_schema = '''||table_schema||'''
    and column name <> '''||column_name||'''
    ), ', ');';
    execute execute_query into column_list;

    -- assigning variable separator_count - code of function janek.cointinstring below, it returns number of occurences of separator in string
    execute_query := 'select max(janek.countinstring('''||column_name||''', '''||separator||''')) from '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||'''';
    execute execute_query into separator_count;

    -- redefining table we're transforming - splitting column_name to an array on delimiter + deleting spaces. If you guys know a way to remove spaces only 'touching' the separator it would be better:
    execute_query := 'with t as (
    select '||column_list||', 
    case when position('''||separator||''' in '||table_name||') > 0 then 
    regexp_split_to_array(replace('||column_name||', '' '', ''''), '''||separator||''')
    elsif length('||table_name||') > 0 then array['||column_name||']
    else null
    as arr
    from '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||')';

    -- main loop, iterates on table in order to transform column 'arr' to separate strings instead of array using union all:
    for i in 1..separator_count loop
        execute_query := execute_query||'
        select
        '||column_list||', arr['||separator||'] as '||column_name||'
        from t
        where arr['||separator||'] is not null
        union all';
    end loop;

    -- removing last union all
    execute_query := substr(execute_query, 1, length(execute_query) - 9);

    -- executing the main query
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE execute_query;

END $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION janek.split_table (table_schema text, table_name text, column_name text, separator text)
  OWNER TO jsiekierski;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION janek.split_table (table_schema text, table_name text, column_name text, separator text) TO jsiekierski;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION janek.split_table (table_schema text, table_name text, column_name text, separator text) TO wsd_users;


-- janek.countinstring function code:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION janek.countinstring(text, text)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
 SELECT(Length($1) - Length(REPLACE($1, $2, ''))) / Length($2) ;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION janek.countinstring(text, text)
  OWNER TO jsiekierski;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `regexp_split_to_table()`, much like the `regexp_split_to_array()` that you are using:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

```
select regexp_split_to_table('hello world', E'\\s+');
```

But your question smells like you're trying to reinvent the `COPY ... DELIMITER ...` command:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

PS -- Tip: use double dollars as string delimiters in meta functions like the ones you're writing: `select $sql$foo, bar, baz$sql$;`

Comment: Thanks. Reinventing the wheel, as usual.